# How to stop timer in Angularjs2

Tags: angular

I have set a time interval in my Angularjs2 application as follows. When logout i need to stop this because after logout also i can see my preloader works that means still the function(`UpdateTransactions`) getting called.

transaction.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    let timer = Observable.timer(45000,40000);
    timer.subscribe(t=> {
        this.UpdateTransactions();
    });
}
```

login.component.ts

```
logout(){
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    localStorage.removeItem("user");
    localStorage.removeItem("paydid");
}
```

How can i stop this timer when logout. Help appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import {TransactionService} from '../services/transaction.service';
import { HttpClient } from '../providers/http-client';
import {Transaction} from '../models/transaction';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {mynum_directives} from '../common/mynum_directives';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-transaction',
  templateUrl: './transaction.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./transaction.component.css'],
})
export class TransactionComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

private transactions:any;
public errorMsg = 'Transactions update request sent successfully!';
public timer;

  constructor(private _service:TransactionService, private _router: Router )    { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.timer = Observable.timer(45000,40000);
    this.timer.subscribe(t=> {
    this.UpdateTransactions();
  });
 }

 ngOnDestroy() {
   this.timer.unsubscribe();
 }

 UpdateTransactions(){
   ////some stuff
 }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could stop timer in `ngOnDestroy()` if that fits you needs.

Ohterwise I would use some kind of global event mediator:

1. Emit on timer start with timer reference in transaction.component.ts
2. Subscribe on this event in login.component.ts and receive the
   reference
3. Stop timer in `logout()`

`ngOnDestroy()` - is a lifecycle hook. It's the same kind as `ngOnInit()` you're already using but is called on component unmounting. So when your component is no more needed it's a kind of destroyed by Angular.
In ohter words, in your transaction.component.ts:

1. Implement `OnDestroy`

   ```
   class TransactionComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {}
   ```
2. Make class property `subscribtion`

   ```
     ngOnInit() {
       let timer = Observable.timer(45000,40000);
       this.subscribtion= timer.subscribe(t=> {
       this.UpdateTransactions();
     });
   ```
3. Create `ngOnDestory()` method
4. Stop timer in that method

   ```
    ngOnDestroy() {
       this.subscribtion.unsubscribe();
    }
   ```

Comment: How could i use `ngOnDestroy()`. can you guide me with a code since im new to Angularjs2

Comment: i have already implented `OnInit` on `TransactionComponent`. is it possible to implement `OnDestroy` along with that. Because im getting an error when trying to implement both.

Comment: yep, it should work like `class TransactionComponent implements OnInit, OnDestory {}`

Comment: but that way it gives me error `cannot find name OnDestroy`. The class has `export` infront of that as well. why is this happening? do i have to import something?

Comment: yep, you have to `import { OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core'`

Comment: I made that correction. but now when i try to logout im getting this error `this.timer.unsubscribe is not a function` . I have updated the question with your suggestions(see edit section). please have a look at it and correct me. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: i tried it in your way. But im still getting the error `No provider for Subscription!`. i made the subscription instance like this in constructor `public subscribtion: Subscription`. But still getting the same error

Comment: this is simpler than that. may be this will help you https://plnkr.co/edit/L4qYTlFDrcVz9VIQBt6O?p=preview see app/app.component.ts

Comment: I've updated example with timer https://plnkr.co/edit/L4qYTlFDrcVz9VIQBt6O?p=preview

Comment: Yes now it is working well. Thanks a lot for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a variable of type Subscription that will hold your subscription, change your code to this:

```
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';

sub: Subscription; 
ngOnInit() {
    let timer = Observable.timer(45000,40000);
    this.sub = timer.subscribe(t=> {
        this.UpdateTransactions();
    });
}

logout(){
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    localStorage.removeItem("user");
    localStorage.removeItem("paydid");
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
}`
```

This assignment lets you unsubscribe from an observable.

Comment: But the logout function is in another component(`login.component.ts`). How can access(`sub`) to unsubscribe?

Comment: Use EventEmitters either through service or parent/child events and listen to them, call this.sub.unsubscribe() when a logout event is triggered

Answer (score -1):

Try to unsubscribe on logout.

```
logout(){
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    localStorage.removeItem("user");
    localStorage.removeItem("paydid");
    timer.unsubscribe()
    });
}
```

consider to make a shared service for user login/logout actions, then you will have access to your subscription. You somehow propagate the login state the login event right?